# Администрирование linux систем

Tags: linux

Хочу научиться админитрировать линуксовые системы. С чего следует начать, находясь в домашних условиях и имея 1 комп?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Поставить вирутальную машину (советую virtualbox) т.к. полная замена реальной ОС вызовет у вас только злость и разочарование.
2. Определиться с дистрибутивом. Если вы планируете заниматься linuxом в промышленности т.е. готовить себя в профессиональной деятельности т.е. тут два основным титана это debian и redhat (rhel, centos). Убунта хороша, но как домашняя ОС, или как десктопная на работе, openSuse, gentoo, slackware linux и пр. все же редки в профессиональном использовании.
3. Далее, когда установите ОС (крайне советую ставить без графики т.е. без любого оконного менеджера. Иногда это назвается server minimal) - следует познать азы работы в командной строке в одной из оболочек (bashshtsch).
4. После того как уверенно будете чувствовать себя в консоли, начинайте осваивать основные сервисы (ftp, ntp, httpd, nfs и пр.)
5. Ну а дальше уже найдете, что узнать еще.

Пишу все подробно, т.к. не один год читал курс Linux в институте =) если есть заинтересованность, могу сбросить учебный план (просто темы от простого к сложному - без самого раскрытия тем)

Answer (score 1):

Поставить можно Убунту, она достаточна проста для новичка. Однако, когда ее освоите, установите в виртуалке Debian и Red Hat (CentOS), т.е. они наиболее часто используются в качестве серверов.

Далее, если хотите стать хорошим админом, для начала:

1. Изучить хорошенько устройство системы: файловая система, конфигурационные файлы, ход загрузки и т.д.
2. Изучить команды. Работа с командной строкой - основа всего.
3. Хорошо освоить создание скриптов в шелле. Для начала - bash, далее можно ознакомиться с ksh, zsh. С-подобные оболочки редко изпользуются в Линуксах, но если их изучите, плохо не будет.
4. Изучить еще какой-нибудь скриптовый язык: Perl и/или Python.
5. Теория сетей и их настройка в Линуксах - как Отче наш. DHCP, FTP, SAMBA.
6. Установка и настройка почтового ящика.
7. Установка и настройка Apache.
8. Хорошо бы ознакомиться с HTML и PHP. Позже поможет для создания веб-морд.
9. Удаленное администрирование.
10. Принципы безопасности  - обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

С установки ubuntu и использования ее в качестве рабочей станции для всех нужд. Далее как чекпоинт - самостоятельная установка gentoo и задания в зависимости от профиля (скажем, изучение ftp-приложений и теории сетей). Для чего вам это нужно?

Answer (score 0):

- Поставить виртуалку
- придумать себе задачу(и)
- выбрать ОС
- выполнять поставленную задачу